# Remove duplicate while appending

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, uniq

I was thinking to create a history file for my utility written in bash. This file is a record of recent server addresses. I will append new addresses to it (one line each time) but I don't want duplicates.

So if the file now is:

```
dept4.abc.edu
dept3.abc.edu
dept2.abc.edu
dept1.abc.edu
```

Now, if I am going to append a `dept3.abc.edu` to the end, I don't want it to be,

```
dept4.abc.edu
dept3.abc.edu
dept2.abc.edu
dept1.abc.edu
dept3.abc.edu
```

Instead, I hope it to be,

```
dept4.abc.edu
dept2.abc.edu
dept1.abc.edu
dept3.abc.edu
```

`sort file | uniq` does not work in this situation, because I want keep the newest server address in the end. Any ideas?

Comment: has the history appending to be realtime?

Comment: Use `grep` to see if the address is already in the file, otherwise append it.

Comment: I was going to ask if the history *cleanup* could be asynchronous. Appending is cheap and fast.

Comment: @Kent, what do you mean by saying "realtime"?

Comment: You can use: `awk '!seen[$1]++' file`

Comment: I think I had similar idea with @kojiro . You can just append everything to the file (or a tmp), then another thread/process does the uniq job. Since if you grep/awk the file every time you appending new line, if the file is big, it would be painful.

Comment: @Kent Then I think I don't need it to be realtime.

Comment: @Daniel to make your example work is easy. if performance was not an issue you can just pick an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FILE=<path-to-history-file>
SERVER=<name-of-the-server-to-add/refresh>

# remove any previously entered occurence
sed -i "/$SERVER/d" $FILE

# append
echo $SERVER >> $FILE
```

Comment: see my update that removes the line instead of just emptying it

Answer (score 1):

Append without caring, whenever. Don't make this synchronously block on the duplicate removal process. Searching and overwriting the entire file every time you want to write to history is an expensive operation.

```
printf '%s\n' dept3.abc.edu >> histfile
```

Then, on a schedule, clean up duplicates without destroying (reverse) order. As a prototypical example:

```
cp histfile histtmp
> histfile
tac histtmp | awk '!s[$0]++' | tac >> histfile
```

(`tac` is `cat` in reverse. If you don't have it you can use `tail -r`.)

The above will clean up duplicates and minimizes the race between updating the file and losing any new history items added during the cleanup. You can add this latter part to your personal cron, for example, to clean the history, say, every 10 minutes:

```
*/6 * * * * ~/histclean
```